# Geoserver - PostGIS database connexion issue - default password always appearing

Tags: passwords, postgis, geoserver

I am using Geoserver 2.18.2 in a Docker image (Docker version 3.1.0) from my Mac (OS Big Sur 11.2.3). My problem is that when I want to add a PostGIS new store a default password always appears. If I modify it with the proper one, it does not change anything as when I apply or save the connexion the default password comes back.

I have checked with colleagues using the same Docker image also on Mac, and I seem to be the only one with this issue. I disabled all passwords managers but still this default password appears.

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser issue, you have a saved password for the GeoServer site and you browser is (helpfully) filling in the password field for you, just delete it and put in the correct password - GeoServer won't connect if you don't supply a password as trusted logins are not supported by the datastore.

Comment: Thank you but this occurs on every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) that I use. I don't save passwords in 2 of them, and I removed the passwords for concerned locations (localhost, 127.0.01, geoserver, ...) on the other one and still the problem occurs on the 3 of them...